# scripts_for_layout generates a different hash on each page load

Tags: javascript, css, cakephp, hash

i have a site in cakephp version 1.2.1.8004, on the admin side scripts_for_layout is used to generate the css and js hash.

Every time on page load it generates a different hash.css file and hash.js file to call the css and js file, so it cannot call the correct css and js file which is present.

i checked on other site where the same hash is generated everytime.

Comment: try to generate your hash in appController and then set it to view after your file name. echo $this->Html->script('file_name'.$hash); let's see if it works

Comment: Please include your hash code - kind of important. :)

Comment: are you really developing a site today with a version of CakePHP that is [5 years old](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/1.2.1) ? If it's an existing app - you should consider at least upgrading to latest 1.x - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22490897/761202) for reasons why.

Comment: no i just am doing maintenance and i am aware of restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to incorrect permissions given to css and js folders. since it could not access the folders it would try to create a new file with new hash everytime.